# Laying of underground AC cables

Tags: cables

I would like to ask, which one is the best way to lay underground low voltage (400V) AC cables, flat or triangular formation. The application that i am interested in is a photovoltaic plant.

[image]

The Neutral and the protective earth (PE) conductor affect the configuration?

Also in case of more than one AC circuits, how much is the optimal distance between the two circuits.

I know that this topic is complicated. Thus, I would be grateful in case that you have a book or article to propose.

Comment: What space is there underground? Any sewer pipes, water mains or gas pipes?

Comment: @SolarMike The application that I am interested in is photovoltaic plants. So there is only soil, no pipes nearby

Comment: Then you should make that clear in your question, there is a huge difference between putting cables down in London streets to green fields.

Comment: @SolarMike , you are right, I edited the questiion

Comment: You probably linked an image of 400kV cabling, since they have an armour. The 400V is much simpler, you put a single cable with 4 or 5 wires.

Answer (score 0):

1. 415Vac (f = ??) 3-phase is not a low voltage.
2. At power frequencies (50 or 60 Hz.) you  can use single wires to make up the cable provided that the insulation is up to standard. This is the cheapest option.
3. Every country has electrical standards that must be obeyed.
4. Underground cables  must be carried in a suitable conduit (orange) at a depth of at least 600mm. Before filling in the trench there must be a labeled plastic film covering the length underground - just in case someone tries to dig holes over the cable.

Comment: Where I am (the UK), 415V is "low voltage".  Anything below 50V is "extra low voltage".

Comment: @SimonB It's a matter of context, I think. When you're working with little microchips and stuff, 5V is a normal voltage, 1V is a low voltage, 12V is a bit high, and 100V is very high. When you're working on the national power grid, 400V is low. Of course building codes are talking about the power grid, so they say that 400V is low.